# Min and Max frequency using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

is it possible to find the min and max frequency using pandas? I have a series of values and i'd like to know the min and max frequency of it appearing. Example for 1, it appears three times out of 24 counts. Therefore, average frequency is 3/24 or 1/8. Which can be derived with count of 1 / total.

However, what i'm looking for is finding the min & max of 1 which:

- min: 0 (the number of times other values appearing between first 1 and the second 1)
- max: 14 (the number of times other values appearing between second 1 and the third 1)

sample DF:

```
╔════╗
║ X  ║
╠════╣
║  1 ║
║  1 ║
║  8 ║
║  5 ║
║  8 ║
║ 11 ║
║  7 ║
║ 11 ║
║ 12 ║
║  7 ║
║  2 ║
║  2 ║
║  6 ║
║  7 ║
║  9 ║
║  2 ║
║  1 ║
║  3 ║
║ 10 ║
║  2 ║
║ 10 ║
║ 13 ║
║  4 ║
║  6 ║
╚════╝
```

```
data = {'X':[1,1,8,5,8,11,7,11,12,7,2,2,6,7,9,2,1,3,10,2,10,13,4,6]}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#changed sample data for possible non 1 before first 1 occurence
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'X':[5,8,1,1,8,5,8,11,7,11,12,7,2,2,6,7,9,2,1,3,10,2,10,13,4,6]})
#print (df)
```

You can compare values by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and create groups by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), remove groups with `0` (if exist some values befor first 1) and last group (also is necessary remove if last value of column is `1`) by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with inverted mask by `~` and then use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with subtract `1`:

```
s = df['X'].eq(1).cumsum()
s = s[~s.isin([0, s.max()])].value_counts().sub(1)
print (s)
2    14
1     0
Name: X, dtype: int64
```

Last get minimal and maximal value:

```
min1 = s.min()
max1 = s.max()
print (min1)
0
print (max1)
14
```

EDIT:

If need also groups before first `1` then use:

```
s = df['X'].eq(1).cumsum().value_counts().sort_index().iloc[:-1].sub(1)
print (s)

min1 = s.min()
max1 = s.max()
print (min1)
print (max1)
```

Comment: @google - I got `2` and `14`, what is correct output. For me it working nice.

Comment: if you want to get for all the remaining value it won't give the proper result try for 5 or 8.

Comment: @google - Not understand, OP counts between 1 values, so remaining group (s.max()) is not necessary

Comment: I might be miss understand the answer please check the below answer

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon - it not working if some values before first `1`, then it create groups for tthis data, test it with changed sample data in answer.

Comment: the original solution works when the non 1 before first 1 occurrence is the max:df['place'].eq(1).cumsum().value_counts().sort_index().iloc[:-1].sub(1)

Comment: the current solution doesn't address the problem when non 1 before first 1 occurrence is the max

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon - yes, exactly. Answer was edited for working correctly if some non 1 exist or non exist before first 1. Solution also working if exist or non exist last value 1

Comment: if the df is as such; df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'X':[8,5,8,5,8,11,7,11,12,7,2,2,6,7,9,25,8,1,1,8,5,8,11,7,11,12,7,2,2,6,7,9,2,1,3,10,2,10,13,4,6]}). which the max is 17, the current solution will still be giving an output of 14

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon - `1,8,5,8,11,7,11,12,7,2,2,6,7,9,2,1,` is not 14?

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon - I got you, you need first group? then remove `0` from isin

Answer (score 0):

This is an improved answer of @jezrael it will loop through all the value and print's min and max.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'X':[1,5,8,1,8,5,8,11,7,11,12,7,2,2,6,7,9,2,1,3,10,2,10,13,4,6]})
#print (df)
for i in set(df['X']):
    s = df['X'].eq(i).cumsum()
    s = s[~s.isin([0, s.max()])].value_counts().sub(1)
    min1 = s.min()
    max1 = s.max()
    if math.isnan(min1):
        min1=max1=0
    print(f"min for {i} is {min1}")
    print(f"max for {i} is {max1}")
```

Comment: thank you for sharing, however, if the df is as such; df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'X':[8,5,8,5,8,11,7,11,12,7,2,2,6,7,9,25,8,1,1,8,5,8,11,7,11,12,7,2,2,6,7,9,2,1,3,10,2,10,13,4,6]}). which the max is 17, the solution provided will be giving an output of 14 instead of 17